# PHP: Elements of array used during page render?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a language system written in PHP. It loads phrases from the database to the array and then displays some of them during the page render. Right now it looks simple:

```
<h1><?=$phrase['phrase_callsign']?></h1>
```

What I need is to know, what particular keys was used during the page rendering procedure.

I have a special function to count and log phrases, so code looks like this:

```
<h1><?=$this->model->phrase('phrase_callsign')?></h1>
```

What I'm asking for, is there are something already built in in PHP instead of the handwritten function to display array keys used? Personally I haven't found anything yet.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What is this function supposed to do? Just make an array containing all the callsigns that were displayed? What do you mean by "during page render"? Page rendering is done by the browser, not PHP.

Comment: Something already built in in PHP... Like gettext? What's your ultimate goal?

Comment: My goal is to understand, is there something already build in PHP to know, what keys of a big language array I used on particular page? Every page loads different arrays and language system is tuned for 3 languages (not limited though, but now there are only 3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to record the keys you are using to retrieve callsigns from the array. I would just define a regular function where you pass in the callsign. It adds it to another array, logs it, and then return the callsign value.

```
function getCallsign($callsign) {
    // log callsign
    array_push($callsigns, $callsign);
    return $phrase[$callsign];
}
```

Comment: You are right. Now I have almost the same function of my own. I was just courious, is there something already built in in PHP :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a list of all the callsigns that were displayed, just push them onto a variable:

```
<h1><?php $all_callsigns[] = $phrase['phrase_callsign']; echo $phrase['phrase_callsign']; ?></h1>
```